# CSS div position changes when window is resized

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked before - I have looked at previous questions and can't get this one to work.

I have a webpage with text and images, all specified in terms of percentages. The text and images are each inside their own divs, with one large parent div. The page looks fine when the browser window is at full size, but when I minimise, image positions move and the overall look is unprofessional. How do I get these to stay?

The parent div looks like this (page must be scrollable, otherwise I would have used position: fixed to solve the issue):

```
div.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and then I have individual images specified as such:

```
   div.image1 {
       position:absolute; left:0%; 
       top:40%; border: none;   
       transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
    }

    div.image2 {
      position:absolute; left:25%; 
      top:40%; border: none;    
      transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
    }
```

html:

```
<div id="base" class="container"> 

...

<div class="image1">
<img src="images/one.jpg" alt="my image">
</div>

<div class="image2">
<img src="images/two.jpg" alt="my image">
</div>

...

</div>
```

Comment: Since all your widths are specified in percentages, you will also have to specify the width of the images in percentages, otherwise they won't change in size as the outer elements shrink.

Comment: I have tried <div class="image1">
<img  width = "50%" src="images/one.jpg" alt="my image" >
</div> but I end up with the same problem.

Comment: Instead of using 50%, try using 46% or so.

Comment: I can't believe that even after 3 months, nobody has thought to ask you how you _want_ it to look. Can you provide a screenshot of the problematic situation at a small screen size and some mockup of how it should look?

Comment: That is very kind of you to ask. Strange, I gave up on solving this problem and for some reason was reminded of it again earlier today. I uploaded the source code: https://github.com/Carla-de-Beer/Web-development/tree/master/web%20page. It contains the .html file and images used. Initially, when opened in Firefox, the webpage displays fine, but when the window is minimised, the images get jumbled, regardless of attempts to put them in divs. I tried to stick to %'s for defining size and position so as to allow for portability across devices. I would really like to know how to solve this issue.